# What foreach(_ => ()) this mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I found this `foreach(_ => ())` in a code that uses Monix stream, I am not understanding the meaning. Can someone explain me this?

`monix_concurrent_subject.foreach(_ => ())`

Comment: Please provide more context. By itself, this statement doesn't do anything

Comment: Can you please share more code? It's sort of weird, as it likely won't do anything useful.

Technically `foreach` means `apply this function I'm passing to every element in the collection", and `_ => ()` is a syntax to create an anonymous function that takes an element (via wahat's called "eta-expansion" - but that's gory tech details) and returns a Unit value `()`. But than `foreach` discards the return value

So, e.g. `List(1, 2, 3).foreach(_ => ())` would return unit and then discard it for `1`, `2` and `3`.

Comment: This function does nothing but if you add it to a stream - it will trigger processing of a stream to provide input for this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As *urmaul* explained in the comments, it depends:

- If the datastructure is eager, it does nothing. Examples are `List`, `Option` etc.
- If the datastructure is lazy, it initialises its content. An example is a `Stream`.

Also as `foreach` returns nothing, it implies that somewhere will be a Side-Effect in the code before the `foreach`.

If you check the API ([ConcurrentSubject.html#foreach](https://monix.io/api/2.2/monix/reactive/subjects/ConcurrentSubject.html#foreachL(cb:A=%3EUnit):monix.eval.Task[Unit])) it states:

> `foreachL(cb: (O) ⇒ Unit): Task[Unit]`
>   Creates a new Task that will consume the source observable, executing the given callback for each element.

Answer (score 4):

`()` represents *the* value in the type of `Unit`. It is perhaps unusual-looking but it is a true value nevertheless, akin to how `42` represents a value in the type of `Int`. For example, we can write

```
val u: Unit = ()
```

similarly to

```
val i: Int = 42
```

`()` does not carry much meaning beyond indicating some side-effect occurred in a function.

Now consider the following function of type `Int => Unit`

```
(x: Int) => ()
```

Note how we do nothing with parameter `x` on the right of `=>`, that is, it is not used at all. We can express this meaning explicitly using an underscore `_`

```
(_: Int) => ()
```

or even simply

```
_ => ()
```

if type inference can figure out the types. Applying an argument to this function

```
((x: Int) => ())(42)
```

results in nothing interesting. So putting these pieces together we get perhaps the following interpretation of meaning of `_ => ()`:

- do nothing effect
- trivial effect
- no operation effect
- effect without effect

However despite `_ => ()` having no *direct* effect it may have some *indirect* effect when passed to `foreach` as explained by pme.

Regarding

```
monix_concurrent_subject.foreach(_ => ())
```

it seems to me here `foreach(_ => ())` is more of a hack to achieve something for which `monix_concurrent_subject` should really provide a proper method.